# Implement WPF TreeView of the same structure as another TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, uielement

I have a TreeView which data source is generated in runtime through code to which I don't have access. Its hierarchical data, nodes of tree with 2, 3 or 4 depth levels. I have to make the same structured tree with RadioButtons corresponding to every object in first tree. Is there a way to iterate through every element of TreeView or another method to do my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, we use `DataTemplate`s, or in your case `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s to define how our data should be presented. You already have the data in the first `TreeView` and that should be accessible from its `ItemsSource` or `Items` properties. Therefore, all you need to do is to define another `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to display the same data object the way that you want it. There is no need to manually iterate through all of the nodes from the original `TreeView`.